# JEditorPane translucent background selection bug

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jeditorpane, visual-glitch

I have a JEditorPane, inside a JScrollPane (both transparrent). These are inside a JPanel which have a translucent background. When i select the text inside the JEditorPane i get this strange bug:
[image]

So the other elements which arent in the same JPanel, "ghost" around the selection, more seen in this screenshot:[image]

Java GUI is a first for me, i've only done server-side applications with no gui's.

Code for the panel:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class NewsPanel extends JPanel {

    private JEditorPane newsArea;


    public NewsPanel() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBackground(new Color(226, 0, 0, 179));
        loadContent();
        setSize(500,400);
    }

    private void loadContent() {
        newsArea = new JEditorPane();
        newsArea.setEditable(false);
        newsArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        newsArea.setSelectionColor(Color.GRAY);
        newsArea.setOpaque(false);
        newsArea.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));

        HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
         StyleSheet styleSheet = kit.getStyleSheet();
         styleSheet.addRule("A {color:#0088CC}");
         styleSheet.addRule("#newsHeader {font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;color:#339933;}");
         styleSheet.addRule("#newsBody {font-size:10px;padding-left:20px;}");
         newsArea.setEditorKit(kit);


        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(newsArea, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        scrollPane.getViewport().setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
        scrollPane.setViewportBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
        scrollPane.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isOptimizedDrawingEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    public void reload() {
        removeAll();
        loadContent();
        validate();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix? I'm sure its something simple, but like i say, i'm new to UI's

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: agree .....................

Comment: otherwise search here how is that possible (two different ways)

Comment: Note that at 160 LOC I would consider that source to be 'short' enough (though it also needs a `main(String[])` to actually put it on-screen).  But if I try to copy/paste it into the question, it loses the formatting.

Comment: Gist Updated, Being new to the UI, i'm not sure what creates updates etc, but from things i've discovered around the internet of things that may cause updates, i've left those in.

Comment: *"Gist Updated,"*  Copy/paste the SSCCE as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20311598/edit)!

Comment: You said it loses the formatting so i thought best to keep it on the gist, but it looks like it formats anyway

Answer (score 0):

> These are inside a JPanel which have a translucent background. When i select the text inside the JEditorPane i get this strange bug:

Check out [Backgrounds With Transparency](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for the probably problem and a couple of solutions.

Comment: According to NetBeans, AlphaContainer (which that link is suggesting) doesnt exist O.o

Comment: @DanSpiteri, Which is why you download the code from that site, or if you don't like downloading code then you need to customize the paintComponent() method of your own classes. The link also gives an example of that approach.